# Trello-like application with public issue tracking features

Tags: web-apps, project-management, issue-tracker

I would like to have a public-facing card-based (or similar) project management application to allow users of our small community to see what our development team is working on.

Software like Trello would work, but (as far as I can tell) there is no way in Trello to allow public users to make private suggestions.

The ideal workflow I would like to see is:

1. Member of the public community enters a suggestion, bug report, etc., which creates a private card in an inbox viewable by the team.
2. Team members choose to move private cards to an appropriate public column, or delete them.

I'm curious if anyone has suggestions for an application that can achieve this out of the box - certainly a workaround would be to use separate systems and simply have team members create cards on a publicly viewable board, but I was hoping to find something integrated.

I had hosted in mind but self-hosted would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Phabricator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phabricator) does this.

It has workboards, which I believe is what you mean by "Trello-like".
Example: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/tag/outreach-programs-projects/

[image: Phabricator Trello-like workboard]

It also has various levels of public/private, I don't know much about it but it can be hinted from this issue discussion: https://secure.phabricator.com/T4893

Any member of the public can submit a private task using this feature, so I guess you can reword it, or reuse the mechanism: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Phabricator/Security#A_direct_way_to_submit_a_security_report_as_a_private_task

Comment: Especially appreciate the link to that issue discussion, thank you. I'll leave unaccepted a bit to solicit other suggestions but this is far closer than I've found available so far.